# FreeBSD phpEclipse installation error

Tags: freebsd, phpeclipse

Im new to FreeBSD and I'm attempting to install PHP-Eclipse.  During the installation process I get the following error.  Does anyone know what it mean and how to fix it?  Thanks.
[image]

Below is the the output:

```
 [echo] +---------------------------------------+
 [echo] + Finishing ant project jaxws
 [echo] +---------------------------------------+

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 12 seconds
gmake[2]: Leaving directory `/usr/ports/java/openjdk6/work/jaxws/make'
/bin/mkdir -p /usr/ports/java/openjdk6/work/build/bsd-i386/hotspot/outputdir
/bin/mkdir -p /usr/ports/java/openjdk6/work/build/bsd-i386/hotspot/import
cd  ./hotspot/make && \
gmake JDK_TOPDIR=/usr/ports/java/openjdk6/work/jdk JDK_MAKE_SHARED_DIR=/usr/ports/java/openjdk6/work/jdk/make/common/shared EXTERNALSANITYCONTROL=true         TARGET_CLASS_VERSION=5 MILESTONE=fcs BUILD_NUMBER=b24 JDK_BUILD_NUMBER=b24 FULL_VERSION=1.6.0_30-b24 PREVIOUS_JDK_VERSION=1.6.0 JDK_VERSION=1.6.0_30 JDK_MKTG_VERSION=6u30 JDK_MAJOR_VERSION=1 JDK_MINOR_VERSION=6 JDK_MICRO_VERSION=0 ARCH_DATA_MODEL=64 COOKED_JDK_UPDATE_VERSION=300 COOKED_BUILD_NUMBER=24 ANT_HOME="/usr/ports/java/openjdk6/work/apache-ant-1.8.2" ALT_OUTPUTDIR=/usr/ports/java/openjdk6/work/build/bsd-i386/hotspot/outputdir ALT_EXPORT_PATH=/usr/ports/java/openjdk6/work/build/bsd-i386/hotspot/import ALT_SLASH_JAVA=/NOT-SET ALT_BOOTDIR=/usr/local/jdk1.6.0 ALT_LANGTOOLS_DIST=/usr/ports/java/openjdk6/work/build/bsd-i386/langtools/dist all_product
gmake[2]: Entering directory `/usr/ports/java/openjdk6/work/hotspot/make'
Makefile:375: target `/Xusage.txt' given more than once in the same rule.
cd /usr/ports/java/openjdk6/work/hotspot/make; \
gmake VM_TARGET=product generic_build2 ALT_OUTPUTDIR=/usr/ports/java/openjdk6/work/build/bsd-i386/hotspot/outputdir
gmake[3]: Entering directory `/usr/ports/java/openjdk6/work/hotspot/make'
Makefile:375: target `/Xusage.txt' given more than once in the same rule.
mkdir -p /usr/ports/java/openjdk6/work/build/bsd-i386/hotspot/outputdir
cd /usr/ports/java/openjdk6/work/build/bsd-i386/hotspot/outputdir; \
gmake -f /usr/ports/java/openjdk6/work/hotspot/make/bsd/Makefile \
       LP64=1 JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/jdk1.6.0 OUTPUTDIR=/usr/ports/java/openjdk6/work/build/bsd-i386/hotspot/outputdir GAMMADIR=/usr/ports/java/openjdk6/work/hotspot MAKE_VERBOSE=y HOTSPOT_RELEASE_VERSION=20.0-b12 JRE_RELEASE_VERSION=1.6.0_30-b24 HOTSPOT_BUILD_VERSION= product
gmake[4]: Entering directory `/usr/ports/java/openjdk6/work/build/bsd-i386/hotspot/outputdir'
cd bsd_amd64_compiler2/product && gmake -w " LP64=1 "
gmake[5]: Entering directory `/usr/ports/java/openjdk6/work/build/bsd-i386/hotspot/outputdir/bsd_amd64_compiler2/product'
gmake[6]: Entering directory `/usr/ports/java/openjdk6/work/build/bsd-i386/hotspot/outputdir/bsd_amd64_compiler2/product'
Compiling /usr/ports/java/openjdk6/work/hotspot/src/share/vm/adlc/adlparse.cpp
rm -f ../generated/adfiles/adlparse.o
/usr/bin/g++ -D_ALLBSD_SOURCE -D_GNU_SOURCE -DAMD64 -I/usr/ports/java/openjdk6/work/hotspot/src/share/vm -I/usr/ports/java/openjdk6/work/hotspot/src/share/vm/prims -I/usr/ports/java/openjdk6/work/hotspot/src/cpu/x86/vm -I/usr/ports/java/openjdk6/work/hotspot/src/os/bsd/vm -I/usr/ports/java/openjdk6/work/hotspot/src/os_cpu/bsd_x86/vm -I/usr/ports/java/openjdk6/work/hotspot/src/share/vm/adlc -I../generated -DASSERT -O2 -pipe -fno-strict-aliasing -DTARGET_OS_FAMILY_bsd -DTARGET_ARCH_x86 -DTARGET_ARCH_MODEL_x86_64 -DTARGET_OS_ARCH_bsd_x86 -DTARGET_OS_ARCH_MODEL_bsd_x86_64 -DTARGET_COMPILER_gcc -DCOMPILER2 -DCOMPILER1  -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions -pthread -fcheck-new -m64 -pipe -DTARGET_OS_FAMILY_bsd -DTARGET_ARCH_x86 -DTARGET_ARCH_MODEL_x86_64 -DTARGET_OS_ARCH_bsd_x86 -DTARGET_OS_ARCH_MODEL_bsd_x86_64 -DTARGET_COMPILER_gcc -DCOMPILER2 -DCOMPILER1  -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions -pthread -fcheck-new -m64 -pipe -Werror -g -c -o ../generated/adfiles/adlparse.o /usr/ports/java/openjdk6/work/hotspot/src/share/vm/adlc/adlparse.cpp 
/usr/ports/java/openjdk6/work/hotspot/src/share/vm/adlc/adlparse.cpp:1: sorry, unimplemented: 64-bit mode not compiled in
gmake[6]: *** [../generated/adfiles/adlparse.o] Error 1
gmake[6]: Leaving directory `/usr/ports/java/openjdk6/work/build/bsd-i386/hotspot/outputdir/bsd_amd64_compiler2/product'
gmake[5]: *** [ad_stuff] Error 2
gmake[5]: Leaving directory `/usr/ports/java/openjdk6/work/build/bsd-i386/hotspot/outputdir/bsd_amd64_compiler2/product'
gmake[4]: *** [product] Error 2
gmake[4]: Leaving directory `/usr/ports/java/openjdk6/work/build/bsd-i386/hotspot/outputdir'
gmake[3]: *** [generic_build2] Error 2
gmake[3]: Leaving directory `/usr/ports/java/openjdk6/work/hotspot/make'
gmake[2]: *** [product] Error 2
gmake[2]: Leaving directory `/usr/ports/java/openjdk6/work/hotspot/make'
gmake[1]: *** [hotspot-build] Error 2
gmake[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/ports/java/openjdk6/work'
gmake: *** [build_product_image] Error 2
*** Error code 1

Stop in /usr/ports/java/openjdk6.
*** Error code 1

Stop in /usr/ports/java/openjdk6.
*** Error code 1

Stop in /usr/ports/java/eclipse.
*** Error code 1

Stop in /usr/ports/java/eclipse.
*** Error code 1

Stop in /usr/ports/java/phpeclipse.
```

Comment: A screenshot is nice, but a logfile is better. Especially the lines before this error message.

Comment: I added the code above.  Is this all the information your looking for? If not, could you provide the commands to gather whats required. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be the -m64 in the compiler flags.

Did you have set any custom CFLAGS or CPUTYPE in /etc/make.conf? If yes remove them

If not, you might try to install openjdk from a binart package with pkg_add

Comment: After messing around I decided to remove openjdk via AppCafe, then reinstalled via ports and now PHPEclipse installed correctly, for the most part.  I seemed to install, but the php functionality is not there.  I know I can install a php plugin, but doesn't that defeat the purpose of having phpeclipse and java eclipse in the port system?  Also, what's the difference between AppCafe and the port system?  I don't understand why PHPEclipse would install with one but not the other.  Thanks

Comment: I installed the php plugin and it works fine, but I would also like Javascript support if possible.  I'm moving from Linux's PHP Eclipse to PcBSD's PHP Eclipse.